# iOS7, gradient as background scrolls away in table view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios7

I want to apply a gradient as a background for an entire view. E.g. I have a table view and I want the table view to be transparent and the gradient background of the underlaying view should shine through.

I found this resource: http://www.danielbeard.io/blog/2012/02/25/gradient-background-for-uiview-in-ios/

and with

```
CAGradientLayer *bgLayer = [GradientBackground blueGradient];
bgLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view.superview.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:0];
```

I managed to add a gradient to the background. However when I scroll the table view, the gradient scrolls away too.

What should I do to prevent the gradient from scrolling away? Either the gradient should scroll simultaneously with the table, or the gradient should be applied to a underlaying view that does not scroll.

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: add gradient to table superview and make it transparent:)

Comment: @sage444 can you show some code plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new UIView with one of its layer set to the `CAGradientLayer` and assign that view to `tableView.backgroundView`. Let the cell color be `clearColor`.

Answer (score 1):

example of code, add sublayer in viewWillDisplay method

```
_contentHolder = [UIView new];
[self addSubview:_contentHolder];        
_tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero
                                                  style:UITableViewStylePlain];
_tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[_contentHolder addSubview:_tableView];

CAGradientLayer *bgLayer = [GradientBackground blueGradient];
bgLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
[_contentHolder.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:0];
```

Comment: must content holder be a property or what is the reason you did not declare it?

Comment: oh, yes, this just few cuts from live project